# CSS <li> issue with jquery and quicksand

Tags: jquery, html, css, quicksand

I have a page with jquery and quicksand plugin that works fine if I have the same size images.
If I have add an different size image it does not show up correctly.

Page: -removed-

I presume it has something to do with the CSS and I cannot see what the issue might be.

Size test-1 looks fine but Size test-2/3 have the issue that the smaller images do not start to populate the page at the left side. It should use the empty space left of the big image as well.

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `adjustHeight: 'dynamic'`?
This is probably what is causing it.

When I click on Test2 I get a big image showing up, the file name is 010.png.
But when I inspect the page before clicking on Test2, 010.png isn't there at all.

** EDIT

I see, it uses ajax to pull other pages.
I don't see anything wrong actually. It is working how it should...

Comment: Yes i have tried remove it, putting it on false and auto as well.
It does not fix the issue.

Correct, the last 3 menu items only have the big image.

Comment: I hope someone else might know how to fix the 'issue'.

Comment: I'm looking at it. Trying to help. But I can't see anything wrong. It works just fine. Maybe could you try and be more specific? Thanks

Comment: It depends on the screen resolution(div set to 1200 now) but if we look at Size test-2 the fourth image should be in the empty place. and fifth image on place four etc. At least thats what i want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working correctly; that's how floats work. You could give [jquery.masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) a try though. Add [the script](http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js) to your site, and call masonry on `.wmshowcase`

```
$('.wmshowcase').masonry({
  itemSelector: 'li'
});
```

I have to say I haven't tested it :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply, didn't know about masonry, going to give that a try.

Comment: It seems like quicksand and masonry aren't easy to combine. But I just discovered [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html), which does exactly what you need. You may give it a try if you're still struggling :P

Comment: Yeh, im still strugeling, going to try isotope, thanks scumah.